# How could a planet have zero surface caves?

Tags: planets, geology, underground, caves, tectonics

What could cause a planet to naturally have **zero** caverns with surface openings apart from small impact hollows in the sides of craters and crevices carved in cliffs?

To be specific, zero large caverns and cave systems with openings on the surface.

*(Subsurface caves could exist. BUT if anyone has an idea on how zero caves on the surface AND below the surface could be possible then please feel free explore that idea as well because the less caves the better)*

Comment: Which kind of planet? What are the surface conditions on this planet?

Comment: @L.Dutch Any kind of planet. I'm looking for the ideal planet to have these sort of conditions. But most of its area should have a solid surface at least... having a planet with a global magma ocean would be a cheap cop out to this sort of question.

Comment: I find "any kind of planet" too broad. Jupiter is not the same as Mercury.

Comment: Make it a gas planet or a young, still molten planet.  Here is a mistake i see many people make, i call it the star wars syndrome: a planet doesn't need to be just one Thing. Planets are huge. It might not be the case here, but ask yourself if it wouldn't be enough to have no caves locally because most stories are localized

Comment: @L.Dutch: "Most of its area should have a solid surface at least" would seem to rule out Jupiter, at least as far as we know...

Comment: @Mehrdad, are you sure metallic hydrogen (which is supposed to be in the depths of Jupiter) does not form caves?

Comment: @L.Dutch: I have no idea if it does, and I'm not sure where you got the impression that I thought that...

Comment: @Mehrdad simply to point out that the name "gaseous giant" doesn't rule out the presence of a solid surface somewhere

Comment: @L.Dutch: Uhm... scientists believe Jupiter has **liquid** metallic hydrogen on its surface (if it even has any solid surface that might be composed of solid metallic hydrogen underneath), and the OP specifically said *"most of its area should have a **solid** surface"*, so Jupiter is pretty clearly excluded.

Comment: Huge _extremely rare_ cement meteor impact.

Comment: I suspect that if gravity on the planet was strong enough to eliminate caves then there wouldn't be any cliffs or other surface features. But maybe you could gloss over that.

Comment: @Raditz_35: Beautifully lampshaded in Stargate SG-1's "Solitudes" episode, in which Carter sees a frozen landscape and immediately (rather stupidly) declares "it's an ice planet" ... only to later discover that she'd landed on Antarctica.

Answer (score 40):

Solid is a relative thing

- No caves in sand
- No caves in water
- No caves in magma
- No (permanent) caves in ice sheet
- No caves in soft soil
- No caves in peat bogs

In short:

- No caves in anything fundamentally unstable
- Only caves where you have surface rock

An old, geologically stable world, where the mountains have eroded down. Land is low lying and either swampy, jungle/forested, desert or coral island, with floating ice caps at both poles.

Comment: Ice sheets are not necessarily cave free, they fracture, form holes from run off melt water, etc.

Comment: @Firelight, I'm running on the fact that while they may briefly exist, it'll be a fleeting existence in the general instability of the medium.

Comment: You forgot gas planets

Comment: @Vylix, the op mentioned in the comments that he'd like solid surface

Comment: @Separatrix If the medium is unstable then as one fracture or hole seals up another would probably form (And from the perspective of a human, around which most stories are told, the life span of such features aren't really fleeting).

Comment: @Firelight: right, it depends on what timescale is relevant.  If the OP wants “no caves that vampires could hide in during the day”, then ice sheets do have such caves and so won’t suit them.  If the OP wants “no caves that would preserve prehistoric remains”, then ice sheets would suit their purpose just fine.

Answer (score 14):

I expect the [plains of Pluto](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto#Surface) doesn’t have any caves<sup>※</sup> because the material is plastic on a time scale shorter than geologic time.  The “minerals” (carbon monoxide, nitrogen, and chunks of water) flows like tar or silly putty, filling in any voids.

Meanwhile, you avoid processes that create caves.  We get limestone caves due to acid and limestone — a planet without those won’t get caves carved by water to this extent.  Lava tubes leave caves: make your volcanoes such that they don’t crust over and drain, or always collapse, etc.

---

※ Do you count crevasses in glaciers as caves or pits?
IAC they are a transient phenomenon.

Comment: What you've said here about Pluto is totally contrary to the New Horizons data. The surface of Pluto is young and geologically active. Also, do you have any supporting evidence for this claim that cryoice "flows"? I'm curious about that since it does not jive with my knowledge of ice rheology.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto#Surface «frozen nitrogen and carbon monoxide ices … polygonal cells which are interpreted as **convection** cells that carry **floating blocks** of water ice crust and **sublimation** pits towards their margins; there are obvious signs of **glacial flows** both into and out of the basin. It has **no craters** that were visible to New Horizons, indicating that its surface is less than 10 million years old.»

Comment: Cryoice rheolovy: Look up the videos from SETI Seminars. The lead scientist gave a wonderful presentation on the newly discovered geology of Pluto.  An earlier talk was about ice on Europa and included an explaination of how it *convects* and an analysis of the circumstances in which the **convection turns over the surface** (as opposed to a static lid).

Comment: Sublimation, glaciers, floating blocks of ice -- sounds like a great recipe for caves! Full disclosure: I got my PhD studying fumarolic ice caves and I now am doing a postdoc at NASA JPL. I don't know much about cryoice yet but my impression was that it would undergo brittle rather than plastic deformation, so maybe those glaciers are crevassed like crazy! (I count crevasses as caves :-)

Comment: I guess it depends not only on the material (this is not water!) as well as (as explained for Europa) the grain size and heat gradient.

Comment: I read a little more about this and confirmed that although the term "flow" is used to describe movement of solid N on Pluto, the actual deformation is brittle rather than ductile, [except maybe between 30-33K](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019103509004813). 
 N glaciers would therefore have crevasses and all sorts of other caves, which is the main question here. I don't understand why you bring up heat gradient, grain size, and Europa. By the way, Europa is nearly all water ice at the surface, and Pluto is also primarily water ice bedrock (with areas of N / CO2 / CH4).

Comment: By the way, is this the SETI Seminar you're talking about? https://youtu.be/R_ZGFx6-xXs

Comment: @foobarbecue no, that is an old pre-encounter overview and naturally doesn’t say anything about Pluto's geography.  I brought up rhe Europa video because the speaker explains how ice convects and an analysis of the circumstances in which the convection turns over the surface (as opposed to a static lid)

Comment: Could you please provide the link to the SETI video you're talking about? I'd really like to watch it. And now I see you mentioned Europa in the second comment, I had forgotten about that. I know a lot more about Europa than Pluto and feel it has high speleogenetic potential (although not quite as high as Enceladus) -- we could take this discussion to a chat room or something if you want to continue it.

Comment: I’ll look for the specific videos.

Answer (score 7):

Well most caves are formed by erosion, more specifically by various water related forms of erosion. So the easiest way to have a planet with no caves what so ever is to have a planet that has no water.

No water means no sedimentary rock in the first place (no life to die and be compressed) and no means by which that rock could be dissolved and eroded.

There are no oceans to form sea caves and coastal erosion, no rivers to carve out canyons and caves, no ice to crack rocks and form caves.

The only remaining forces likely to form caves are plate tectonics and volcanic activity. You might get Lava tubes and primary caves but they would be far less common.

Of course, as far as telling a story set on such a planet is concerned you would probably struggle as it would likely be a completely barren, lifeless rock; which may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: "No water = no life to die" isn't necessarily true, it would just mean a radically different path for the development of life from what is feasible on Earth.

Comment: @Myles True, but I'm not sure that such life would form sedimentary rock like limestone, plus if there is no water to dissolve the rock after it has formed then having sedimentary rock isn't a problem.

Comment: Definitely not limestone like rock as water is quite integral for that but possibly many other things that wouldn't be feasible on Earth.  Also to see how wind could carve a cave. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeolian_processes#/media/File:MoabAlcove.JPG

Comment: no water does not mean no sedimentary rock, windblown sediment can form sedimentary rock.

Answer (score 5):

Cover the planet with a liquid, e.g water or lava (at the right pressure and temperature). Any caverns will be below the liquid, i.e. below the surface.

Answer (score 5):

Would I be wrong to say that all "large caverns and cave systems" are formed in limestone?

I may be wrong but if you pick a famous cavern like Carlsbad Caverns (New Mexico) or Lascaux (France), or [Karst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karst), they're in limestone.

Now [limetone has a biological origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limestone):

> Limestone is a sedimentary rock, composed mainly of skeletal fragments of marine organisms such as coral, forams and molluscs. Its major materials are the minerals calcite and aragonite, which are different crystal forms of calcium carbonate (CaCO3).
>
> About 10% of sedimentary rocks are limestones. The solubility of limestone in water and weak acid solutions leads to karst landscapes, in which water erodes the limestone over thousands to millions of years. Most cave systems are through limestone bedrock.

So, perhaps a planet which never evolved corals and moluscs, for whatever reason, might do?

Comment: Lava tubes are also well known caving destinations.

Comment: So, a planet where the extremely liquid lava that gives rise to lava tubes does not exist or does not errupt above sea-level? I don't know if that's achievable via a small change to natural abundances or tectonic activity compared to Earth.

Comment: Or a planet where "molluscs" and "corals" build silica shells not carbonate shells. We have the diatoms here with silica shells, but they never evolved past single-celled organisms.

Comment: Yes, you would be wrong! There are large caves in marble, quartzite, gypsum, ice, and volcanic rocks, to name a few.

Answer (score 3):

A planet with no mountainous area and even hilly area (littlest altitude possible), and important tidal range (as important as the highest point on the planet).

With the movement of the sea, sand and other light solid will fill all the surface cavern.

Tide could destroy all the cavern in an other way. See the example of [Io](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Io_(moon)), one of the satellite of Jupiter, the tidal effects are sufficient to move the rocks and all the planet surface. It will destroy all the cavern on and in the planet (but maybe it could create some).

Comment: Titan is a satellite of Saturn https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(moon). Titan is unique amongst the worlds we have explored precisely because it has fluids on the surface to mimic the actions of water on Earth such as sedimentation and cave creation.  Did you mean Io?

Comment: @pojo-guy I am pretty sure he meant Io. Io is pretty famous for having "land tides".

Comment: Need to check ! I may have a little confusion with my solar system knowledge

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps some bear species takes it upon themselves to fill the naturally occurring caves so that they're sealed off. Maybe said species finds it useful somehow? Perhaps it's a religious thing for these bears?

Answer (score 2):

I believe a planet without tectonic activity would work.

Most of the large caves on earth which aren't man-made are a result of either volcanoes or limestone decay.

Most, although probably not all, volcanoes on earth are created around the tectonic plates. Thus, eliminating those plates could potentially eliminate volcanoes which eliminates volcanic caves.

Limestone caves are a result of the tectonic plates lifting the sea-floor above sea-level and then letting erosion run its course. With no tectonic plates, there's no lifting which means no erosion of the limestone to create caves.

This does leave open the possibility of caves under water, but I think it covers the "dry" planet surface.

Comment: In the distant past, Mars had volcanoes without technic plate movement. But yes, maybe you want a planet whose core cooled so long ago that all lava tubes near the surface have been destroyed by erosion or meteor impacts.

Answer (score -1):

If there was never anything liquid on the surface, you would never get caves. No water = No caves. Caves can still form an most rocks as long as there is liquid water and a crack and somewhere for the water to flow to. Another thing is magma will create caves (think lava tubes) after it has flowed and hardened the surrounding rock the remaining liquid drains and you get caves.

Ice can also create caves, if you got rid of all the liquid on a planet I think its safe to say you'd get zero caves.